# How to UPDATE rows in one table where there duplictaes in another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would be massively grateful if someone can help me write a query to update our orders system due to a dupe issue.

We have an orders table and a customers table.

I've identified some duplicate rows in our customers table where the email address and password are the same on unique rows - and are associated with unique live orders by CustomerNumber which exists in each table. This is bad as when a customer logs in to their account, they won't see all of their orders, rather they'll only see the orders associated with the highest customer ID (see login SQL below)

**Identify duplicate user accounts:**

```
SELECT
    emailaddress,
    PASSWORD,
    count(*)
FROM
    scustomers
JOIN orders ON orders.customernumber = customers.CustomerNumber
WHERE Completed = 1
GROUP BY
    emailaddress,
    PASSWORD
HAVING
    count(*) > 1
```

**Login SQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM scustomers WHERE EmailAddress = :EmailAddress AND (Password = :Password) ORDER BY CustomerNumber DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

I need to write a query that:

- Updates the "orders" table
- Updates the "CustomerNumber" column
- Sets the "CustomerNumber" column to be the highest "CustomerNumber"
- WHERE the "customers" table has more than 1 rows with has an
  identical "Email" and "Password" column

Where do I start?!

Our system has been fixed so that any customer order a new product by logging in will always use the highest possible associated CustomerNumber so this really is about fixing existing data.

**UPDATE:**

I've never used SQL Fiddle, but here is some sample data that I hope will help you.. help me!

**CUSTOMERS:**

*customernumber, email, password*

3272,   jwilson@email.com,  9a098e0bade9b4f2ac4ecdf86111cf7e

10001,  jwilson@email.com,  9a098e0bade9b4f2ac4ecdf86111cf7e

**ORDERS:**

*ordernumber,customernumber,status*

123457, 3272, 'LIVE'

123456, 10001, 'LIVE'

I need to update OrderNumber: 123457 to have the CustomerNumber of 10001, not 3272.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data with sqlFiddle ?

Comment: sql fiddle will be very helpfull!

Comment: sample data added to question. thank you for looking!

Comment: set an unique index in that field.. it'll show an error while inserting duplicates...

Comment: Ideally your password hashes should be unique - I'd suggest adding a random unique salt to your hashing technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : create a temporary column to store the correct CustomerNumber

```
ALTER TABLE scustomers
    ADD COLUMN id_tmp INT NOT NULL;
```

Step 2 : retrieve the correct CustomerNumber

```
UPDATE scustomers
    INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT
            emailaddress,
            PASSWORD,
            MAX(CustomerNumber) AS id
        FROM
            scustomers
        GROUP BY
            emailaddress,
            PASSWORD
        ) AS duplicate ON scustomers.emailaddress = duplicate.emailaddress AND scustomers.PASSWORD = duplicate.PASSWORD
    SET id_tmp = id;
```

Step 3 : update order table with the correct CustomerNumber

```
UPDATE orders
    INNER JOIN scustomers ON orders.customerNumber = customers.CustomerNumber
    SET orders.customernumber = id_tmp;
```

Step 4 : delete duplicate customers

```
DELETE FROM scustomers
    WHERE customernumber <> id_tmp;
```

Step 5 : remove the temporary column

```
ALTER TABLE scustomers
    DROP COLUMN id_tmp;
```

Comment: I'll give this a go and report back. Thank you (so far!)

Comment: Step 2: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'duplicate.emailadress' in 'on clause'

Comment: I forgot a "d" --> emailaddress

Comment: This works perfectly! I have tested it out by putting my email address into a WHERE clause and all my test orders now fall into one account for that password. So scary taking the WHERE clause off though! Probably not one for a Friday afternoon... I'll wait until Monday, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am just giving idea about sql query you need to write for loop

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( customernumber) , i.email
 FROM scustomers i INNER JOIN ( SELECT k.email FROM scustomers k GROUP BY k.email
 HAVING COUNT( `customernumber` ) >1 )j ON i.email = j.email GROUP BY i.email

 Out put :
   ----------------------------
    customernumber    Email 
   ---------------------------
    1,2,3            ss@ss.ss
```

After this all duplicate will come in on field.explode the new customernumber get last value in that array (Ex: 3 is last value)

```
update  `orders` set `customernumber`='last array value(Ex: 3)' WHERE `customernumber` in (customernumber from above  query(1,2,3) )
```

For delete duplicate records

```
DELETE n1 FROM scustomers n1, scustomers n2 WHERE n1.customernumber< n2.customernumber AND n1.email= n2.email
```